# easy server and client communication

Tags: networking, server, network-programming, client, backend

I want to create a program for my desktop and an app for my android. Both of them will do the same, just on those different devices. They will be something like personal assistants, so I want to put a lot of data into them ( for example contacts, notes and a huge lot of other stuff). All of this data should be saved on a server (at least for the beginning I will use my own Ubuntu server at home).

For the android app I will obviously use java and the database on the server will be a MySQL database, because that's the database I have used for everything. The Windows program will most likely be written in of these languages: Java, C#c C++, as these are the languages I am able to use quite well.

Now to the **problem/question:** The server should have a good backend which will be communicating with the apps/programs and read/write data in the database, manage the users and all that stuff. But I am not sure how I should approach programming the backend and the "network communication" itself. I would really like to have some relatively easy way to send secured messages between server and clients, but I have no experience in that matter. I do have programming experience in general, but not with backend and network programming.

side notes:
I would like to "scale big". At first this system will only be used by me, but it may be opened to more people or even sold.
Also I would really like to a (partly) self programmed backend on the server, because I could very well use this for a lot of other stuff, like some automation features in my house, which will be implemented.

EDIT: I would like to **be able** to scale big. I don't need support for hundreds of people at the beginning ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to research Socket programming. They provide relatively easy, secured network communication. Essentially, you will create some sort of connection or socket listener on your server. The clients will create Sockets, initialize them to connect to a certain IP address and port number, and then connect. Once the server receives these connections, the server creates a Socket for that specific connection, and the two sockets can communicate back and forth.

If you want your server to be able to handle multiple clients, I suggest creating a new Thread every time the server receives a connection, and that Thread will be dedicated to that specific client connection. Having a multi-threaded server where each client has its own dedicated Thread is a good starting point for an efficient server.

Here are some good C# examples of Socket clients and servers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

As a side note, you can also write Android apps in C# with Xamarin. If you did your desktop program and Android app both in C#, you'd be able to write most of the code once and share it between the two apps easily.

I suggest you start learning socket programming by creating very simple client and server applications in order to grasp how they will be communicating in your larger project. Once you can grasp the communication procedures well enough, start designing your larger project.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure how I should approach programming the backend and
>   the "network communication" itself.

Traditionally, a server for your case would be a web server exposing [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) (JSON). All clients need to do http requests and render/parse JSON. REST API is mapped to database calls and exposes some data model. If it was in Java, it would be Jetty web server, Jackson Json parser.

> I would really like to have some relatively easy way to send secured
>   messages between server and clients,

Sending HTTP requests probably the easiest way to communicate with a service. Having it secured is a matter of enabling HTTPS on the server side and implementing some user access authentication and action authorization. Enabling HTTPS with Jetty for Java will require few lines of code. Authentication is usually done via [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) technique, and authorization could be based on [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). You may go beyond of this and enable encryption of data at rest and employ other practices.

> I would like to "scale big". At first this system will only be used by
>   me, but it may be opened to more people or even sold.
>   I would like to be able to scale big. I don't need support for
>   hundreds of people at the beginning

I anticipate scalability can become the main challenge. Depending on how far you want to scale, you may need to go to distributed (Big Data) databases and distributed serving and messaging layers.

> Also I would really like to a (partly) self programmed backend on the
>   server, because I could very well use this for a lot of other stuff,
>   like some automation features in my house, which will be implemented.

I am not sure what you mean self-programmed. Usually a backend encapsulates some application specific business logic.

- It could be a piece of logic between your database and http transport layer.
- In more complicated scenario your logic can be put into asynchronous service behind the backend, so the service can do it's job without blocking clients' requests.
- And in the most (probably) complicated scenario your backend may do machine learning (for example, if you would like you software stack to learn your home-being habits and automate house accordingly to your expectations without actually coding this automation)

> but I have no experience in that matter. I do have programming
>   experience in general, but not with backend and network programming.

If you can code, writing a backend is not very hard problem. There are a lot of resources. However, you would need time (or money) to learn and to do it, what may distract you from the development of your applications or you may enjoy it.

The alternative to in-house developed of a backend could be a **Backend-as-a-Service** (BaaS) in cloud or on premises. There are number of product in this market. BaaS will allow you to eliminate the development of the backend entirely (or close to this). At minimum it should do:

- REST API to data storage with configurable data model,
- security,
- scalability,
- custom business-logic

**Disclaimer**: I am a member of [webintrinsics.io](http://www.webintrinsics.io/) team, which is a Backend-as-a-Service. Check our website and contact if you need to, we will be able to work with you and help you either with BaaS or with guiding you towards some useful resources.

Good luck with your work!